# How save user when using custom login credentials instead of firebase authentication

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, authentication

I am making a app in kotlin and spring boot as backend framework . in this app  i will use custom username and password for login instead of firebase google authentication. So How can i save user so that he doesn’t have to login again and again, and load data to that specific user when open app which is pre login by that user

I have not tried it yet , just want to know about that.